# How to send a variable in an AJAX site?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

I created an Ajax navigation system but I've an issue when I want to send a variable.
I've an index.php like this

```
<script src="navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <div id="pageContent"></div> 
    <a href="#page1">page1</a> 
<a href="#profile">profile</a>
```

This is navigation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkURL();
    $('a').click(function (e){
        checkURL(this.hash);
    });
    setInterval("checkURL()",250);
});

var lasturl="";
function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;
    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}

function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#','');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",   
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the load_page.php page:

```
<?php
    if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    include('pages/'.$page.'.php');
?>
```

This is the issue: when I load profile.php page I want to see values by GET... example:

```
<?php 
    $nome_utente = $_GET['user']; 
    if(!$_GET['user']) { 
        print 'Attention! You have to insert a username'; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print $nome_utente; 
    } 
?>
```

To do this I tried to change the link in index.php

```
<a href="#profile?user=test">profile</a>
```

But this doesn't work because load_page.php doesn't find the "profile?user=test.php" page.
What do I have to do to send a GET variable at profile.php, from a link in index.php?
I've to edit JS or PHP code?

Comment: Please don't use caps lock in your title. Using caps won't get you any more attention than a well formatted title. In fact, it might get you a bit less due to it often being read as shouting.

Comment: Apart from why would you want todo this, your script is vulnerable to xss & directory traversals/includes attacks

Answer (score 1):

Mixing get/post variables is considered poor practice, but is easily done:

```
function loadPage(url) {
    url=url.replace('#','');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php?user=whatever_you_want_here",
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---your 'get' query
```

The other optiont would be to add the 'user' parameter to your ajax data line:

```
data: { page: url, user: whatever_you_want_here }
```

The first one would make 'user' available in $_GET, the second one would make it available in $_POST.